# Help understanding the migrate wubi documentation?

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi

I'm looking at the [MigrateWubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) page but I'm not sure if I need to change the partition directories to the ones I created, and if so, I'm not too sure which ones I need to change.

Here are the partitions I've made:
[image]

Should I just copy and paste: sudo bash wubi-move.sh /dev/sda5 /dev/sda6 into my terminal or something else?

Also, do I enter just this one line or do i need to enter any other commands in there? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have `/dev/sda6` labeled as `/` (root) and `/dev/sda7` labeled as `/home` and `/dev/sda5` as swap... so the command you'd use is:

```
sudo bash wubi-move.sh /dev/sda6 /dev/sda5 --home=/dev/sda7
```

Note, it appears that `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/sda7` aren't completely empty. This is required by the script before it will let you migrate (the script will warn you and exit if this is the case).

If you don't want to migrate with a separate `/home` partition, then the command will be (the first positional parameter is the target partition and the second is the swap partition):

```
sudo bash wubi-move.sh /dev/sda6 /dev/sda5
```

Don't worry too much about it - because the script checks the partitions and won't let you migrate if you get the order wrong. You can also run it with the `--check-only` argument and it will just perform the checks without making any changes. (Even without that it will prompt you to confirm before making changes.)

PS. that `691 GiB` that's unallocated can't be used unless you first increase the extended partition (`/dev/sda4`) to include it. Once you've done that you can create logical partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But when i enter the first line, it returns with: ryan@ubuntu:~$ sudo bash wubi-move.sh /dev/sda6 /dev/sda5 --home=/dev/sda7
[sudo] password for ryan: 
bash: wubi-move.sh: No such file or directory
ryan@ubuntu:~$    I have  wubi-move-2.3.tar.gz extracted to my downloads folder. PS. I can format gewd.

Comment: You're in your `/home/ryan` directory, but the script is in `/home/ryan/Downloads/wubi-move-2.3`. So first enter: `cd ~/Downloads/wubi-move-2.3` (its case-sensitive)